# Copy Constructor on a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash, queue, copy-constructor

I just have a quick question about my program. I've having a problem with my copy constructor. The program stops working and I've located the problem down to my copy constructor. It seems that the do while loop I made is not ending like it's supposed to. I'm sure I've made some mistake, but I can't for the life of me think of what it is. The loop is supposed to end when my rear is a NULL, but when that happens it crashes my program.

My header file.

```
#ifndef CONGERA3_H
#define CONGERA3_H

const int MAX_STRING = 6;
typedef char Element300[MAX_STRING + 1];

class Queue300
{
    public:
        Queue300 ();
        Queue300 (Queue300 &old);
        ~Queue300();
        void enQueue300 (const Element300);
        void deQueue300 (Element300);
        void view300();

    private:
        struct Node300;
        typedef Node300 * NodePtr300;
        struct Node300
        {
            Element300 element;
            NodePtr300 next;
        };
        NodePtr300 front, rear;
};

#endif
```

My implementation file. I've just included the copy constructor and the enQueue and deQueue, since everything else is running fine. I also left in the regular constructor in case there's a problem with that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "congera3.h"
using namespace std;

Queue300::Queue300 ()
{
    rear = NULL;
    front = rear;

    return;
 }

Queue300::Queue300 (Queue300 &old)
{
    //Node300 * newNode;
    //newNode = new Node300;
    Element300 temp;
    do
    {
        old.deQueue300(temp);
        //cout << temp;
        enQueue300(temp);
    }while (old.rear ->element != NULL);

    return;
}

void Queue300::enQueue300 (const Element300 element)
{
    Queue300 temp;
    Node300 * newNode;
    newNode = new Node300;

    strcpy (newNode -> element, element);
    newNode -> next = rear;
    rear = newNode;

    if (newNode -> next == NULL)
    {
        front = newNode;
    }
    cout << newNode -> element;

}

void Queue300::deQueue300 (Element300 element)
{
    Node300 * newNode;
    newNode = new Node300;
    newNode = rear;
    int i = 0;
    if (rear -> next == NULL)
    {
        strcpy (element, newNode -> element);
        rear = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
         while (newNode -> next != NULL)
        {
            newNode = newNode -> next;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        strcpy(element, newNode -> element);
        newNode = rear;
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
        {
            newNode = newNode -> next;
        }
        newNode -> next = NULL;
     }
}
```

Comment: what happens when your program crashes? what is the output immediately before for a sample run with inputs? what does gdb say? have you done a backtrace on your segfault or whatever error you have?

Comment: what do you expect your deQueue300 function to do?

Comment: I used a bunch or print statements to and they all printed fine, I had one at the top of my deQueue function in the if statement after setting rear to NULL that printed. I then put a print statement in the copy constructor after the enQueue that printed and the program crashes right after that one prints. My deQueue300 function is supposed to remove the front element from the linked list.

Comment: Are you sure the nodes are iterating from one to the next one?

Comment: @C0UG3R Please change the parameter being passed to the `Queue300` copy constructor to `const Queue300 &old`.  If your code doesn't compile, then ask yourself -- why are you mutating `old` to simply make a copy?  In other words, why are you dequeing `old` in the copy constructor?  Does that sound right to you?  That goes against what the copy constructor is supposed to accomplish.  If it were a *move constructor*, then yes, the parameter being passed would be "emptied out".

Comment: @C0UG3R Just to add -- you shouldn't be `dequeing` anything in the copy constructor.  What you're missing is a function that can "look inside" the `old` and just get a copy of the data at a certain position.  Then add that data to the back of the new list.  It could be a `private` function, but this is what you're missing to accomplish getting the copy constructor to work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I figured that deQueue would be the quickest way to get the elements and copy them over into the copy list. I didn't think about changing the old list. So I guess I'm unsure how I should go about copying the old list then. EDIT: Just saw your new comment, I'll give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: @C0UG3R  For a copy constructor, the passed-in value should not be mutated.  Otherwise you will get weird behavior and invariably bugs that are very hard to diagnose.  You also are missing an assignment operator to go along with the copy constructor.  If you had a function called "transfer_your_stuff_to_me", then dequeing the passed-in parameter would make a little sense, but it shouldn't be done for the copy constructor.